# Миниатюры на php

Tags: php

Как создать миниатюрное изображение из более крупной картинки без потери качества? В Инте смотрел - там какие-то талмуды написаны. Хотя это же вроде делается в пару строк...

Comment: > В Инте смотрел - там какие-то талмуды написаны. Хотя это же вроде делается в пару строк...

Талмуды действительно есть но действительно хороший скрипт занимает совсем не пару строк. Давайте уточним какой должна быть реализация? Т.е. Изображение должно создавать уменьшеную копию при загрузке на сервер либо изображение уже лежит на сервере и его нужно просто уменьшить и вывести?

Answer (score 1):

Без потери качества - понятие растяжимое в данном случае, т.к. при сжатии качество как-нибудь да потеряется.

```
<?php
function sharpen_image($img) {
    $filter = array (
        array( 0,  -1,   0),
        array(-1,   9,  -1),
        array( 0,  -1,   0),
    );
    $divisor = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $filter));

    if (!imageconvolution($img, $filter, $divisor, 0))
        return false;
    else
        return $img;
}

//максимальные ширина и высота:
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize("image.jpg");

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
sharpen_image($image_p);//можно обойтись без шарпинга

imagejpeg($image_p, "image_preview.jpg", 100);//качество от 1 до 100
//если есть желание выдавать прямо в браузер, то до этой строчки вставляем
//соответствующий хедер: header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
//и меняем второй аргумент на null: imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagic умеет делать это

Comment: Я о другом речь веду.